# Share a global NSURLSession amongst view controllers

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

I have read on the iOS dev docs that a NSURLSession object is intended to be shared among the application's components and specific tasks are created from it. I am wondering what is the best way to share the NSURLSession object? One possible approach was to create it within the App's delegate and have View controllers obtain the delegate and schedule a task and I could either return the task or implement a callback whenever the data is finished downloading to share that with the caller. I am unsure what if this is a good approach, I would appreciate some feedback and suggestions thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is two ways to do it:

First one is to create a singleton class and do all your nsurlsession task in that class.

Second would be define it in AppDelegate they way you are saying.

I would prefer first one.

Comment: I prefer the first method as well. Instantiating singleton objects should not be the job of the `AppDelegate`. Singleton objects should be able to lazily create themselves when a class property such as `sharedInstance` or `defaultInstance` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass your UIViewController and hand the NSURLSession from controller to controller in prepareForSegue.

That way you avoid the singleton pattern and your code remains easily testable.

Comment: If I do this, I would just keep setting the NSURLSession's delegate to the active controller correct?

Comment: You could do that, yes.

Comment: @luk2302 I was going to take the Singleton approach but decided to look at Stackoverflow to see if there are any best practices.  Could you please elaborate on the why singleton pattern makes code difficult to test?  That will really help me divide on best pattern.  It appears that subclassing UIViewController approach will not work (or atlas will need some duplication) if the view controllers that need to call networking APIs are managing different types of views (TableView, TextView etc)